# VS code sometime not showing the output in terminal

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, visual-studio-code, printing

While debugging python code, sometime the print() output is not showing up in the terminal
this can happen while in debug mode and in free run mode

when I re-lunch the debugger or run again the output shows up

I'm printing long list or dictionary with 4 levels of dictionaries

Does anyone can help to fix this?

```
    if(crc.CRC16(set, len(set), 0xffff) == [0, 0]):
        print("======= Settings ===========")
        print([hex(i) for i in set ])  # THESE PRINT sometime 
        #not showing output in Termina
        print ("       ")
        set = set[3:]  # remove first 3 bytes (indx 0,1,2) which 
        # are header 
        set = set[:-2]  # remove last two bytes CRC (indx -1 -2)
        ConfigurationDict = settings.FillConfigDict(set)
        settings.PrintConfigDict(ConfigurationDict)  """ THESE 
        PRINT sometime not showing output in Terminal"""

        #settings.PrintConfigDictWithPandas(ConfigurationDict)
        settings.PrintConfigDict(ConfigurationDict) 
        Data2Send = 
        settings.FillSettingListToSend(ConfigurationDict) """ a 
        list of configuration data"""
        #print([hex(i) for i in Data2Send])
        Frame2send =  settings.Write_Rqst+Data2Send+crc.//
                      CRC16(settings.Write_Rqst+Data2Send,//
                      len(settings.Write_Rqst+Data2Send), 0xFFFF)
        ser.write(Frame2send)
        print ("       ")
        TT = [hex(i) for i in Frame2send]
        print(" ##################   Frame2send     ")
        """print([i if (len(i) ==4) else i[:2] + '0' +i[2:] for i 
        in TT]) # print hex in the format 0xmm so 0xc will be 0x0c    
        """
                                                               
   else:
       print(" CRC ERROR")
print("done")
```

Comment: Can we get a small piece of code that isn't working?

Comment: code added
it's a normal print for either a list or a dictionary